# How to post to a LinkedIn wall using access token of the user who authorized?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

#### PHP code

```
$base_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/';
$url = $base_url . 'shares';
$xml  = '<share>';
$xml .= '<comment>' . 'test'. '</comment>';
$xml .= '<content>';
$xml .= '<title>' . 'TEST' . '</title>';
$xml .= '<submitted-url>' . 'http://www.google.com' . '</submitted-url>';
$xml .= '<description>' . 'description' . '</description>';
$xml .= '</content>';
$xml .= '<visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility>';
$xml .= '</share>';

$signature = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer('my_consumer_key', 'my_consumer_secret', NULL);
```

How can I get a $token and $secret variable which is oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
when *all* I get is an access token when sending an authorization request to the user?
Is there a way I can get the **oauth_token** and **oauth_token_secret** using the **access token**?

```
$token = new OAuthConsumer($token, $secret, 1);
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'POST', $url, array ());
$request->sign_request($signature, $consumer, $token);
$header = $request->to_header();
$response = _linkedin_http_request($url, $header, $xml);

/*
 * Some internal helper functions...
 */
function _linkedin_http_request($url, $header, $body = NULL) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if ($body) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ($body == 'token_request') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
        }
        else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header, 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        }
    }

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: please elaborate and that link is not valid  ?

Comment: You get your API key and secret here: [linkedin.com/secure/developer](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) To get the rest, check out the OAuth documentation that will describe the steps to follow: OAuth Authentication

Comment: Same issue I am also getting , I want the users oauth_token and oauth_secret who has authorized me for the access token . please let me know